# Determine which USB port was used

Tags: android, usb

The question is: how to determine (programmatically) which USB port was used when the USB flash drive was plugged in?

**Context:**

I am developing an app for an Android TV Box that lets you view files from a Pendrive. My device has 3 USB ports. I would like to know which of the port was used (some kind of ID, port name, whatever that could help me identify it in the code).

**What have I done:**

1. I read the android docs regarding [USB as a host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host). None of the classes contains such information. The API is listing only devices which are plugged in but there is no information about the USB sockets. The `deviceName` is a string containing the path to a device file created in the android system but it is changing every time I plug in a USB flash drive (it looks like this `/dev/bus/usb/007/008` the numbers, in the end, are different each time).
2. Looked into android sys files by `adb shell` command but couldn't find anything that describes the USB ports and says which one is currently in use.

Maybe someone encountered a similar problem? I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a bit unusual to need to know the specific usb port a device connected on. Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve?
I from memory the /dev/bus/usb/xxx/yyy are allocated when the device connects, so, yes. they would normally be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

The Android operating system does not expose the information you are looking for.

Only with root access to the underlying Linux system below, can that information be obtained.

Use `lsusb` to enumerate the usb devices, and `dmesg`  and `mount` to correlate the drive's mount point.